# AdSense deductions for Invalid Traffic - is that's the reason?

Tags: google-adsense, traffic, revenue

More than $2,700 has been deducted this month from my earnings at AdSense for invalid traffic. The only new thing about my account this month is that I opened a new website. All that revenue is coming from that new website, but I didn't add this website at my sites section in my adsense account here exactly.

[image: where my sites at]

A friend of mine who's an expert in AdSense told me it's because my website isn't added to my sites list at my AdSense account. I'm not sure what to do — I want to be 100% sure that this is the reason. Is my friend correct. If so, can I ask AdSense to add this money back to my account? How would I make that request?

Comment: when i say this money i mean this month

Comment: You said about invalid traffic, what is the exact message you got. And your main traffic is organic? or you're getting from social media and such a thing, and your ads are close to any button like next or previous?

Comment: [Authorise site is optional step in adsense](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/65062?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=2781147), if you have not select in previous then all of website can use your ads, and those clicks will going to add in your account. So make sure, you have setup that kind of things in your account or not.

Comment: the news website doesn't get any traffic from social media what so ever and the authorized site thing it's inactive i didn't turn it on and i just checked right now and it's off but i added the new site and will see what will happened now

Comment: What does "didn't add this website at my sites section in my adsense account here exactly" mean?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3suz.png follow this image and see where i am at and you will find it it's a place where you add the sites that you want your ads to show on them but it's optional if it's not working then no worries

Comment: You said something about invalid traffic. So what is your main traffic source. Google news? As I already said Adsense team will never specify exact reason behind that, you have to find it yourself.

Comment: AdSense has deducted a seemingly random amount of money for "invalid traffic" from my account each month for years.   They don't give any explanations and have no mechanisms for appeal.  I've never had a month where the total deducted was that much higher than the surrounding months though.